# Вывести картинку через php

Tags: php, wordpress

Есть следующая картинка:

```
<img src='/wp-content/uploads/banner-shoppadma-1_300x600-min.jpg' alt='sale70' width='300' height='600'>
```

Как правильно вывести ее через?

```
echo "";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для HTML используйте двойные кавычки, для (PHP, JS) одинарные, тогда не будет таких проблем.

```
echo '<img src="/wp-content/uploads/banner-shoppadma-1_300x600-min.jpg" alt="sale70" width="300" height="600">';
```

Вот так можно, только не знаю зачем Вам это нужно.

Может я Вас не совсем понял и Вы хотите отрендерить картинку средствами PHP, тогда так:

```
$url = '/wp-content/uploads/banner-shoppadma-1_300x600-min.jpg';
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
imagejpeg(imagecreatefromjpeg($url));
```

Comment: То что нужно, спасибо. Ответ смогу принять через 6 часов: так пишет система при клике по галочке.

Comment: @СтаниславКремса Пожалуйста.